# Ruby on Rails: An optional argument makes me to repeat lines of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optional-arguments

I have following code fragment:

```
if my_string.comment.blank?
  xml.string(:name => my_string.name) {
    xml.text(variation_value(my_string, variation_id))
  }
else
  xml.string(:name => my_string.name, :comment => my_string.comment) {
    xml.text(variation_value(my_string, variation_id))
  }
end
```

what I do not like here is that xml.string and its block are mentioned two times. How could this be rewritten?

Could it be rewritten to have two different xml.string calls, but one block for them both?

Or may be `:comment => my_string.comment` could be passed or not passed, depending on `my_string.comment.blank?` condition?

P.S. This fragment uses Nokogiri to form XML, and there is no "string" method to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I can think about is prepare arguments hash beforehand:

```
args = {:name => my_string.name}
args[:comment] = my_string.comment unless my_string.comment.blank?

xml.string(args) {
  xml.text(variation_value(my_string, variation_id))
}
```

But maybe a cleaner way exists.

Comment: Why the space between `args` and `[`?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1: Use merge to construct the options**

```
xml.string(
  {:name => my_string.name}.merge(
    my_string.comment.present? ? {:comment => my_string.comment} : {}
  )
){
  xml.text(variation_value(my_string, variation_id))
}
```

**Approach 2: Use tap to construct the options**

```
xml.string(
  {:name => my_string.name}.tap { |o| 
    o[:comment] = my_string.comment if my_string.comment.present? 
  }
){
  xml.text(variation_value(my_string, variation_id))
}
```

**Approach 3: Pre-create the options**

See the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662544/163203)

I prefer the approach 3 followed by 2.